# jQuery why some of my icons start looking incorrect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I use jQuery mobile on my app, Everything was ok but I just noticed that these two items below does not look correct anymore.

First one is a selection and there used to be a small arrow instead of that empty gray circle.

And second is the spinnig wheel there used to be the animation wheel now there is an empty gray circle..

Dont know which part of code change really effected this, any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using JQM CDN links or you host them locally? if you host them locally, images of JQM should be under _JS/images/_, e.g. `JS/jquery1.3.0.js` and `JS/images/jqmicons.png`

Comment: @Omar yes thats what I have changed recently, i use locally now what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mayu Mayooresan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348301/mayu-mayooresan) answer is correct for using CDN-Hosted jQuery-Mobile.

If you want to Host it locally, [download jQuery Mobile](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.zip), extract the files to folder `/js/`. The structure should look like this:

HTML files, directly in *root* folder

> webapp/Index.html

Scripts under *root/JS* folder

> webapp/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css
>
> webapp/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
>
> webapp/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js

Images under *root/JS/images/* folder

> webapp/js/images/ajax-loader.gif
>
> webapp/js/images/icons-18-black.png
>
> webapp/js/images/icons-36-black.png
>
> webapp/js/images/icons-18-white.png
>
> webapp/js/images/icons-36-white.png

In your HTML file:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: tnx but somehow it does NOT works..you have any idea what is missing, just added the images folder into JS. the other directories were already working and exist. but no luck. I also use jQuery mobile-1.8 might be it?

Comment: Try using the latest jquery mobile scripts. http://jquerymobile.com/download/ it doesn't work for all widgets? buttons, listview, checkboxes...etc? can you show the links in `<head>`? and files location?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the reference to the images files. You need to get the images into your project. When you download the library as ZIP file you can find the folder which contains the images.

Else use CDN as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when used with CDN i got some problems on production environment dont really remember the error but something like cant access domain

Comment: if you lost internet connection then CDN won't work. But CDN is better compare to local files. For example if the user used some other site used the same cdn, then your site won't be downloading it again, instead files will be taken from browser cache.