# Jquery Mobile Images not showing up in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an app I built in Phonegap build however the app no longer shows images within the icons etc. So for example the back button shows but doesn't show the little arrow within the back button. The only changes I have made to my app is that I have all the JS files needed for the app stored and referred to locally.

Anyway I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Local files

You are missing the reference to the images files.

They can be found in css/images dyrectory. Or when you download the library as ZIP file you can find the folder called images.

To be more specific:

HTML files, directly in root folder

```
webapp/Index.html
```

Scripts under root/JS folder

```
webapp/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css

webapp/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js

webapp/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js
```

Images under root/JS/images/ folder

```
webapp/js/images/ajax-loader.gif

webapp/js/images/icons-18-black.png

webapp/js/images/icons-36-black.png

webapp/js/images/icons-18-white.png

webapp/js/images/icons-36-white.png
```

This locations were taken from [**Omar's**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762397/1848600

### Remote files

An easier solution would be to link everything to the online resource:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

If it works with them then your problem is in this directory.

Comment: yeah it worked with the online directory before so I guess this is my problem. Would this affect my jQuery itself in anyway as the code worked in the browser before but is no longer working

Comment: @KernElliott it should work normally if you follow the steps above. In jQuery Mobike CSS file, images are taken from subdirectory `/images/`.

Answer (score 0):

I just battled this issue with the missing icons on native devices myself.  Icons appear fine when I used external links as posted above.  I'm concerned about Apple not approving the externally downloaded code in my app, so I continued to try options with my local project files.

I stumbled upon a local setup that works, but may not be recommended.  I tried switching to jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css, instead of 1.3.0 and the icons suddenly appeared!  So my configuration is:

```
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to include the image files as stated above I got it to work on Android and BB when i get a dev key will try it on iOS