# Data clear btn appeare without image

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, input

I use `Jquery Mobile` 1.3.1.

I have a `textbox` when writing it, you should see a button to delete the text:

You can see it on this site:

**http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/textinputs/**

[image]

Here my textbox:

```
<input placeholder="Name" type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="NameTxt" id="NameTxt" value="">
```

I have a button appears, but the image of the X it does not appear.

[image]

I can not understand what the problem is.

Comment: are you using CDN-Hosted files or locally hosted? Does it occur on all icons or only search box?

Comment: Silly question: Do you have [this background image](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/css/themes/default/images/icons-18-white.png) in your local files?

Comment: @Omar. I used locally. and it occur on all icons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761246/jquery-why-some-of-my-icons-start-looking-incorrect/15762397#15762397 you need to add images under `/images` in same folder of jQM css file.

Comment: @Omar. This is not something that should come automatically from the files of JQM?

Comment: No, since you're using locally hosted files. if you use CDN-Hosted, it will work `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle ?