# jquerymobile data-icon issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

If i use CDN hosted javascript and css url inside my html data-icon are displaying correctly. If i use local folder location inside my project its not working. Find the below code for reference. I have the content from the below mentioned CDN url only. Kindly advice what i am doing wrong.

Below code not working, round icon is displaying but i didnt get the info logo "i" inside the icon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="test">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#home" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works if i use CDN url, icon with info symbol coming

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="test">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#home" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery why some of my icons start looking incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761246/jquery-why-some-of-my-icons-start-looking-incorrect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using it locally you will need to upload the icons images to the server. The CDN will be hosting the images for you in the second example as the css is looking in a folder relative to the css file.

Inside the CSS for the icon class you'll see it uses the following:

```
background-image: url(images/icons-36-white.png);
```

So you'll need to download the icons file from jquery. for example from here: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/images/icons-36-white.png

Comment: I have downloaded the css from jquerymobile website and save to my project folder. This file doesn't contain those images???

Comment: If you download it from here you should get the images too: http://jquerymobile.com/resources/download/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.zip

Comment: sorry i didnt download those images

Comment: Your css is in the folder called css. So if you create a folder named 'images' inside this css folder and place the icons in there it should work.

Comment: +1 you should mark this as correct after @DavidMacCrimmon has put so much effort into helping you to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting the CSS style-sheet for jQuery Mobile then you need to also host the images (which are found in the same .zip file that the JS and CSS files came in)

The image sprites should be in a directory named images which is in the same directory as the jQuery Mobile CSS style-sheet (the style-sheet relatively references the images like this: **background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png);**).

[Source Location](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)