# Checkbox in JQuery Mobile doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm trying to use the checkbox in JQuery Mobile, but it doesn't display the checkbox, it only shows a blue square when I hit it, and this blue square disappears when I hit it again.

screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noogx.png]

EDIT:

```
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right"><input type="checkbox" name="legalConsentCheckBox" id="legalConsentCheckBox" value="agree" class="custom" /><label id="legal-checkbox1" for="legalConsentCheckBox" style="font-size:90% !important; color: black !important; " dir="rtl">  02545  </label></fieldset>
```

My desired effect:
[image]

Comment: Code? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Of all honesty, that is a `checkbox` what was your desired effect?

Comment: icon font is probably not included... because the checkbox is showing... you just don't see the "checked" mark.

Comment: Checkbox/radio buttons don't have data-iconpos option. You have to do it by overriding JQM css.

Comment: What version of JQM are you using?

Comment: @KristofFeys what do you mean by icon font?

Comment: @Omar even without the use of data-iconpos option, the problem persists

Comment: @Flea777 version 1.3.1

Comment: @Ahmed cfr. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-custom-1-3-1-button-icons-not-showing

Comment: @Omar Actually, in 1.3.2 checkboxes have data-iconpos. Of course, you need images in the same directory of JQM css file, unded an 'images' directory.

Comment: @Flea777 you're right, never knew that before. Ahmed, are you using a local hosted libraries or CDN-hosted?

Comment: @Omar local hosted libraries

Comment: If icons aren't visible on buttons, then `/images/` directory isn't placed under JQM CSS file as @Flea777 said. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761246/jquery-why-some-of-my-icons-start-looking-incorrect

Comment: @Omar I used the CDN-hosted librarties and it worked! thank you very much.

Comment: @Omar You may want to consider posting this an answer and allowing that the chance to selected.

Comment: @Twisty thanks for your msg :) but this question is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761246/jquery-why-some-of-my-icons-start-looking-incorrect