# jQuery mobile cool icons not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

in this link: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/icons/

I tried to get these icons working but I guess I'm missing the images.

I downloaded all the jQuery mobile version, even one with Sizzling images.

Nothing worked.

I checked the source of the page, and I can't see which version of jQuery they use in the demo/example.

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="css/jquery.mobile.theme.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">
<button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-audio">audio</button>
```

Which version should I use if each .css and .js, and in which order? and where do I get all the images, I also checked the source, and couldn't find the Sprites.

Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery why some of my icons start looking incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761246/jquery-why-some-of-my-icons-start-looking-incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] this line solved the issue, it worked:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css">
```